# emacs define-generic-mode why cannot use regexp-opt?

Tags: emacs, font-lock, backquote

I am trying to make simple major mode for syntax highlighting using `define-generic-mode`. I found that

```
(define-generic-mode 'mytest-mode
  '("//") nil
  '(
    ((regexp-opt '("int" "string" "bool")) . 'font-lock-type-face)
    )
  nil nil "mytest mode"
  )
```

is not working. But if I replace `regexp-opt` call with its manually calculated result, then all works as expected:

```
(define-generic-mode 'mytest-mode
  '("//") nil
  '(
    ("\\(?:bool\\|int\\|string\\)" . 'font-lock-type-face)
    )
  nil nil "mytest mode"
  )
```

So, why I cannot just put `regexp-opt` call in the mode definition?

**EDIT**

Hint about forced evaluation of items in quoted list from Lindidancer's answer:

```
(define-generic-mode 'mytest-mode
  '("//") nil
  '(
    (,(regexp-opt '("int" "string" "bool")) 'font-lock-type-face)
    )
  nil nil "mytest mode"
  )
```

doesn't help: no errors on mode activation but no highlighting also

Second hint about use `list` function to form lists:

```
(define-generic-mode 'mytest-mode
  '("//") nil
  (list
    ((regexp-opt '("int" "string" "bool")) 'font-lock-type-face)
    )
  nil nil "mytest mode"
  )
```

gives error on activating mode: `(invalid-function (regexp-opt (quote ("int" "string" "bool"))))`

same error when trying evaluate:

```
  (list
    ((regexp-opt '("int" "string" "bool")) 'font-lock-type-face)
    )
```

in scratch buffer.

**EDIT 1**

```
(list (list (regexp-opt '("int" "string" "bool")) 'font-lock-type-face))
```

doesn't help also - no errors, no highlighting.

**EDIT 2**

Steps, what I exactly do, are:

1. Execute `define-generic-mode` call in the `*Scratch*` buffer
2. Switch to buffer with some keywords under test
3. `M-x mytest-mode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define-generic-mode 'mytest-mode
  '("//") nil
  `(
    (,(regexp-opt '("int" "string" "bool")) . 'font-lock-type-face)
    )
  nil nil "mytest mode"
  )
```

Comment: After year of torments, you opened my eyes, so I accepted yours answer, thank you)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the call to `regexp-opt` is inside a quoted list, so it isn't seen as a function call.

You can either create the list using functions like `list` or use backquotes, where a `,` means that the next form should be evaluated.

```
`(
   (,(regexp-opt '("int" "string" "integer" "bool" "boolean" "float")) . 'font-lock-type-face)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, your comma syntax return no errors but doesn't highlight text. When i try `(list ((regexp-opt '("int" "string" "bool")) 'font-lock-variable-name-face))` then I recieve `(invalid-function (regexp-opt (quote....`

Comment: It should probably be `(list (list (regexp-opt ...) ' font-lock-type-face))`.

Comment: `(list (list (...` doesn't help also. Updated question.

Comment: Note the `\`` vs. `'` used to quote the list.  You need to use a backtick instead of single quote.  This is also known as quasiquote.